# ESP8266/NodeMCU RESTful HTTP posting

Tags: rest, http, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

The following code runs on an ESP8266 microcontroller, posting a stream of basic sensor readings over HTTP to the Ubidots web service API. The NodeMCU Lua interpreter is used (I want to do it in Lua, don't want to use other alternatives, such as Arduino IDE or MicroPython, right now.)

The "sensor data" seems to work (dummy right now), the timer event to post a reading seems to work, I think the JSON formatting and structure of the POST is basically correct, and the WiFi connection seems to be right, but not the data ultimately reaching the cloud dashboard.

I think I've done something silly in setting up the POST syntax.

I'd appreciate a fresh set of eyes to find the bug.

```
WIFI_SSID = "foo_ssid"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "secret_password"
API_TOKEN = "secret_ubidots_token"
update_period = 5 -- seconds

function format_json(variable1, value1, variable2, value2, variable3, value3)
  -- let's allow three different readings in the nested JSON payload.
  data = '{'..variable1..': {"value": '..value1..'},'
            ..variable2..': {"value": '..value2..'},'
            ..variable3..': {"value": '..value3..'}}'
return data
end

function postUbidots(deviceName, name1, value1, name2, value2, name3, value3)
  connection_out = nil
  connection_out =  net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

  connection_out:on("receive", function(connection_out, payload_out)
    if (string.find(payload_out, "201 CREATED") ~= nil) then
      print("POST OK");
    end
  end)

  connection_out:on("connection", function(connection_out, payload_out)
    data = format_json(name1, value1, name2, value2, name3, value3)
    local post_string = "POST /api/v1.6/devices/"..deviceName.."/?token="
    ..API_TOKEN.." HTTP/1.1\n"
    .."Host: things.ubidots.com\n"
    .."Content-Type: application/json\n"
    .."Content-Length: "..string.len(data).."\n"
    ..data.."\n"
    connection_out:send(post_string)
  end)

  connection_out:on("disconnection", function(connection_out, payload_out)
    connection_out:close();
    collectgarbage();
  end)

  connection_out:connect(80, 'things.ubidots.com')
end

function readSensors()
  -- don't worry about real sensors right now
  -- let's just make up a few dummy variables.
  sensor1_value = 90
  sensor2_value = 65
  sensor3_value = 30
  postUbidots("deviceName", "sensor1", sensor1_value, "sensor2", sensor2_value, "sensor3", sensor3_value)
end

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.setphymode(wifi.PHYMODE_G)
station_config={}
station_config.ssid=WIFI_SSID
station_config.pwd=WIFI_PASSWORD
station_config.auto=true
wifi.sta.config(station_config)

tmr.alarm(1, 1000, 1, function()
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then
    else
        tmr.stop(1)
    end
end)

print("WiFi connected.")
tmr.alarm(1, (update_period*1000), tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function() readSensors() end)
```

Comment: Are you still stuck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you format the HTTP message. Try this:

```
local post_string = "POST /api/v1.6/devices/"..deviceName.."/?token="
..API_TOKEN.." HTTP/1.1\r\n"
.."Host: things.ubidots.com\r\n"
.."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
.."Content-Length: "..string.len(data).."\r\n\r\n"
..data..
```

Reference: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend

Did you know we've got a dedicated HTTP module that greatly simplifies things?
-> https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/#httppost